# What is the cleanest way of setting default values for attributes unless provided by the class call?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently this is what I'm doing:

```
class NewShip:
    def __init__(self, position = (0,0), x_velocity = 25, y_velocity = 15, anim_frame = 1, frame1 = "space_ship_1.png", frame2 = "space_ship_2.png", angle = 0, border_size = 900):
        self.position = position
        self.angle = angle
        self.x_velocity = x_velocity #in pixels per frame
        self.y_velocity = y_velocity #in pixels per frame
        self.anim_frame = anim_frame
        self.frame1 = pygame.image.load(frame1).convert_alpha()
        self.frame2 = pygame.image.load(frame2).convert_alpha()
        self.frame1 = pygame.transform.scale(self.frame1, (128,128))
        self.frame2 = pygame.transform.scale(self.frame2, (128,128))
        self.position = DummyObject()
        self.position.x = position[0]
        self.position.y = position[1]
        self.border_size = border_size
```

but honestly that's quite tedious and makes adding any more facultative attributes a real pain.

Should I just skip the whole 'letting people declare attributes with keyword arguments' thing and just instantiate objects in a fully default state before changing any of their attributes?

EDIT:
apparently this works perfectly:

```
class NewShip:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.angle = 0
        self.x_velocity = 25 #in pixels per frame
        self.y_velocity = 15 #in pixels per frame
        self.anim_frame = 1
        frame1 = "space_ship_1.png"
        frame2 = "space_ship_2.png"
        self.position = DummyObject()
        self.position.x = 0
        self.position.y = 0
        self.border_size = 900
        for element in kwargs: setattr(self, element, kwargs[element])
        self.frame1 = pygame.image.load(frame1).convert_alpha()
        self.frame2 = pygame.image.load(frame2).convert_alpha()
        self.frame1 = pygame.transform.scale(self.frame1, (128,128))
        self.frame2 = pygame.transform.scale(self.frame2, (128,128))
```

that is, just setting all defaults values then overriding them with the keyword args using `for element in kwargs: setattr(self, element, kwargs[element])`

Let me know if there's any cleaner way, though I have to say I'm much more satisfied with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reduce the clutter, you could alternatively define a defaults dictionary attribute `_init_attrs` for example, define your function with `**kwargs` and then `setattr` on `self` with a loop, using `_init_attrs[k]` as a `default` value for `kwargs.get` when no  parameters were supplied:

```
class NewShip:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        _init_attrs = {'angle': 0,
             'anim_frame': 1,
             'border_size': 900,
             'frame1': 'space_ship_1.png',
             'frame2': 'space_ship_2.png',
             'position': (0, 0),
             'x_velocity': 25,
             'y_velocity': 15 }

        for k, v in _init_attrs.items():
            setattr(self, k, kwargs.get(k, v)
```

This makes `__init__` a bit more mystifying but achieves the goal of making it way more extensible while cutting down the size.

Comment: As per my edit I stumbled upon setting defaults value first then using a for loop to override defaults with kwargs, though I have to say your solution using a dict and updating it with kwargs is even more elegant and clean. Thank you very much!

Comment: Also, you don’t really want to just iterate over anything in `kwargs` and call `setattr` for it, as it essentially allows you to overwrite things you don’t want to be overriden. Consider iterating over `_init_attrs` (without updating it), and using `kwargs.get(key, _init_attrs[key])`.

Comment: I like poke's idea but using `.pop` might be even better so that if there are any entries in `kwargs` afterwards an appropriate error can be raised for passing unsupported arguments.

Comment: @poke I'm not sure what you mean. If there's anything I didn't want overriden I could just not put it inside of _init_attrs and simply assign then after iterating over kwargs, could I not?

Comment: With Jim’s original suggestion (using `_init_attrs.update(kwargs)`), you could have specified elements in `kwargs` which were unknown to `_init_attrs` which would then end up in it and would also be set using `setattr`. That yould overwrite members you don’t want ovewritten just by passing them inside `kwargs`. So you should always iterate over the set of safe properties to set (`_init_attrs`), and only apply the changes through that.

Comment: Yup, for example consider having a `foo` function defined and then passing `NewShip(foo=1)`, `foo` is an `int` now; you'd inadvertently allow everything passed to be set as an attribute.

Comment: Well that would also mean that I can't create arbitrary attributes in the declaration, and since I can do `new_ship = NewShip()`, then `new_ship.foo = 3` anyway, I don't see it as much of a problem, you always have to be careful not to override methods when setting an attribute. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Kwantuum for you working on this the contents of the class are well known. This is really just safeguarding, if you want your users (or yourself) to accept arbitrary and/or mis-spelled arguments you can use `update` if you only want your instances to hold a certain set of attributes, use the updated answer (both in essence do what you want albeit with slightly different effects).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Oh one last remark, I noticed while practising that in `for k, v in _init_attrs.items(): setattr(self, k, kwargs.get(k, _init_attrs[k]))`, v is actually already equal to `_init_attrs[k]` so you can use `kwargs.get(k,v)` for something even cleaner. Thank you again for your help!